# Are bass clarinet and tenor sax notations played an octave lower?

Tags: notation, instruments, transposition, saxophone, bass-clarinet

I am totally blind, and I read music Braille. I also use a MIDI keyboard to make musical tracks using a sequencer.

Recently, I had a piece, October by Eric Whitacre, transcribed into Braille music.

I noticed that the bass clarinet and the tenor sax parts have octave markings for third or fourth octave when they probably go outside their range. I transposed them -12 semitones and it sounds about right, but I just want to make sure.

I also noticed this type of arrangement with barbershop music.

Why do they make systems like this?

Comment: Given that both instruments are transposing b-flat instruments, I neither can see what an octave transposition (from the question title) has to do with it, nor the relation to the "duplicate" question given (which is very specific about an *exact* octave, not simply something similar).

Comment: Measure 12 BC 3b. 3/4. Third octave B Quarter slurred to C half.
Measure 13. Common Fourth octave D quarter, slured, cresc, fourth octave E dotted half.
Based on this, it was transposed two half steps in the notation, but I had to transpose it one octave below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, bass clarinet and tenor sax are notated a ninth higher than they sound. So the written middle C (C4) sounds the B♭ a 9th below (B♭2). The point is not to make life difficult for transcribers, but to make it easier for players who play multiple kinds of clarinet or saxophone. [This recent question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71577/key-used-by-clarinet) discusses the reasons further.

Comment: When you say a ninth,do you mean major ninth from Concert C? So, transpose C4 to C3, and then Bb3?

Comment: Just to complicate matters, if you ever encounter a bass clarinet part in the bass clef (a.k.a. _German_ notation), the transposition is a major second.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony Yes, C to Bb means a major ninth downward.

Comment: @DeanRansevycz Note that "German" notation is an abomination unto the lord and should be banned from the planet (and I say this a German, mind you). The entire point of transposing notation is to let players reuse the fingerings they know, and German notation does not achieve that.

Comment: Agreed, @KilianFoth, but i added the comment for completeness. The same goes for bass clef use in Classical period horn parts, double-bass harmonics in the treble clef & myriad other notational idiosyncrasies: all should be purged by fire & sword, but they exist nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Bb2 not Bb3. So, C4 to C3, and down to Bb2.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the dots within a stave is helpful when reading (and writing) for instruments which use only one stave. It helps by the fact that most of the notes are within the 5 lines, 4 spaces, and not put onto loads of little leger lines, which are more difficult to read. Given that a tenor sax is already a transposing instrument may put the dots out of the stave, keeping most inside is a big boon.

Comment: More to the point,  shifting by an octave as well as the second (C to Bb) allows a sax player to use the same fingerings on soprano and tenor for the same written note.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I assumed that was a given - that's one reason why saxes are Bb and Eb, with appropriately placed dots.